# Increment ng-repeat index value in Html

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to increment value of `$index` in `ng-repeat`. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat:x in ProductList">
    <label>{{x}}</label> // if x = 1
        x++; // this is the line i need
    <label style="color:red">{{x}}</label> // x index should be equal to 2
    x++; // this is the line i need
    <label style="color:blue">{{x}}</label> // x index should be equal to 3
</div>
```

in the second time the loop runs, the x index needs to be '4'

Comment: sorry, its unclear what you're asking.

Comment: what you want to achieve ? Will you please share your desired output ?

Comment: see answered below. thats what i need

Comment: so does the result go like `1, 3, 5, 7`?

Comment: Can you lets know your requirement. may be we can suggest you best solution.

Comment: Read [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do following:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in ProductList">
    <label>{{$index}}</label> 
    <label style="color:red">{{$index + 1}}</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: in the second time it will start from index=3 ?

Comment: @Eliad Can you be more specific about what you actually want to do? May be more descriptive.

Comment: and you mean product[$index] and product[$index+1]

Comment: Thanks. If you don't properly explain what you are trying to do, then no one will be able to help you. Usually along with the problems you are facing, its better to explain what you are trying to achieve. Someone else might have better idea on how to achieve the same result some other way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (which is hard to understand), you want to perform different actions for even and odd indexes in your `ng-repeat`. You could use the special properties `$even` and `$odd` from `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in ProductList">
    <label ng-if="$odd">{{x}}</label>
    <label ng-if="$even" style="color:red">{{x}}</label>
</div>
```

If this does not help you, try to give an example of what output you are expecting.

Comment: thank you, but no. all i need is to increase index while running in ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print index value in diff element for each item in your array,

what i will suggest is to create a custom directive and use it on different element here is "label", that we increment the count of index.

Comment: can you please explain more ? i just simpley use ng-repeat as for loop

Comment: here is what i was suggesting you to do, something like this i have created a sample plunker for your reference, hope that will help you to achive some thing that you need,
http://plnkr.co/edit/1HTOlFwuvB4nNKtx64Nl?p=preview